# How to retrieve the names of the music files i upload in firebase storage manually?

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I have uploaded some music files in firebase storage bucket manually, not programmatically.
Is there any way to get the names, the links from which I can stream it in my android application written using java. 
I got similar questions and answers in Stack Overflow but in all cases the uploads are done programatically and not manually like in my case.

I tried searching everywhere but what i always get is an upload that is done programmaticatlly which makes it simpler to get the download url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store the list of files somewhere that is known by your app.  Perhaps it could be in another file in Cloud Storage, or a database.